# Removing object using JArrayItem.Remove("value") not working

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I am trying to remove an object from an existing `JArray`, but when I run the method to delete the property from the `JArray`, the property still exists.

I tried simply using the code below

```cs
JObject rss1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("online.json"));
JObject uList = (JObject)rss1["uList"];
JArray newOnline = (JArray)uList["online"];
newOnline.Remove("value");
```

The code above is almost directly copied and pasted from the Newtonsoft.Json documentation on modifying Json, but only changed to remove the new item instead of adding it. I've tried other post's solutions, but none of them work. Adding the field works as expected, but trying to remove it does not work whatsoever.

Below is the JSON file's contents

```json
{
  "uList": {
    "placeHolder": "placeHolderValue",
    "online": [
      "value"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the expected JSON output of the code being ran

```json
{
  "uList": {
    "placeHolder": "placeHolderValue",
    "online": [
    ]
  }
}
```

And, below, is the actual output of the code being ran

```json
{
  "uList": {
    "placeHolder": "placeHolderValue",
    "online": [
      "value"
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong and not realizing it?

Comment: Can you post input JArray and expected output?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I have edited the post to include expected behavior and actual behavior

Comment: Isn't your `JArray` actually a list of `JValue` and not a list of `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also remove JToken by querying `value` string present in `online` JArray.

Parse string to JObject:

```
JObject rss1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("online.json"));
```

Now remove particular token using below query.

```
rss1.SelectTokens("$.uList.online[?(@ == 'value')]").FirstOrDefault()?.Remove();
```

[Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z0Ap28)

Comment: This worked, thanks a ton! I modified it a little to remove duplicate tokens, just in case there were any duplicates. I plan on using this to keep track of clients that are online, and when a user closes the client it will delete all occurrences of the given user. The line I used to remove _all_ occurrences of the token was `rss1.SelectTokens("$.uList.online[?(@ == 'value')]").ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());`, which Github copilot managed to generate for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've got is that you don't actually have a `string` in your array, you have a `JValue`. The `JArray.Remove` method accepts a `JToken`, but the `JToken` produced by implicitly casing your string to a `JValue` is not equal to the one being removed.

There's one of two solutions that come to mind:

1. Find the item in the array and then pass that to the remove method:

```cs
JToken item = newOnline.FirstOrDefault(arr => arr.Type == JTokenType.String && arr.Value<string>() == "value");
newOnline.Remove(item);
```

2. Use the `.Remove` method of the array item to remove it from the array:

```cs
JToken item = newOnline.FirstOrDefault(arr => arr.Type == JTokenType.String && arr.Value<string>() == "value");
item?.Remove();
```